# Entity framework is not refreshing when i try to update data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm using ADO.NET Entity Framework to work with my instance of SQL Server 2008 R2. Everything was working fine (I was modifying other tables) until I've made new `editEntity` method which couldn't refresh entity after my modification until I restart my program.

This is my query:

```
TD_LIVING living = (from l in _model.TD_LIVING
                    where l.LEASE_START == leaseStart
                      && l.TD_FLAT_ID == flat.TD_FLAT_ID
                    select l).FirstOrDefault(); 

living.LEASE_END = signOffDate;

int changesCount = UpdateContext.SaveChanges();
```

Entity is modified (I've checked the `ObjectStateEntry`), `SaveChanges()` returns 1, but still, when I get list of all `TD_LIVING`, values there are old.

I've tried to use

```
_model.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, living);
```

and when that failed I've tried creating new context to which I attached my entity:

```
badbEntities UpdateContext = new badbEntities();
UpdateContext.Attach(living);
living.LEASE_END = signOffDate;

int changesCount = UpdateContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
```

It didn't help...

Comment: Should `RefreshMode.ClientWins` be `RefreshMode.StoreWins` ?

Comment: @Peter K. I've tried diffrent combinations of RefreshModes and SaveOptions but without result...

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you need:

```
UpdateContext.SaveChanges(living)
```

Otherwise it doesn't know what to update.